# NEED right SELECT MYSQL expression

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 4 tables:
1: arrivals
  warehouse_id
  arrival_id
(1, 1)
2: arrival_data
   arrival_id
   spec_id
   height_id
   size_id
   qty
 (1, 5, 3, 2, 2)
3: movements
   sender (=warehouse_id)
   movement_id
 (1,1)
4: movement_data
   movement_id
   spec_id
   height_id
   size_id
   qty
(1,5,3,2,2)
So to warehouse (id=1) was added spec 5 with size 3 and height 2 and quantity 2
And was moved also to warehouse (id=1) spec 5 with size 3 and height 2 and quantity 2
I need to make query which will return me 
spec_id, size_id, height_id, qty, warehouse
(5, 3,2, 4, 1) Whole quantity(4) and of course arrivals and movements can have several rows with such parameters
I tried to make Query:

```
    SELECT ad.spec_id, ad.height_id, ad.size_id, (SUM(ad.qty)+SUM(md.qty)) as qty, SUM(ad.qty) as arrival_qty, SUM(md.qty) as movement_qty, a.warehouse_id FROM arrival_data ad
LEFT JOIN movement_data md
    ON ad.size_id= md.size_id 
        AND ad.height_id = md.height_id 
        AND ad.spec_id = md.spec_id
LEFT JOIN arrivals a 
    ON ad.arrival_id = a.arrival_id                 
LEFT JOIN movements m 
    ON m.receiver = a.warehouse_id 
        AND md.movement_id = m.movement_id

GROUP BY ad.spec_id, ad.size_id, ad.height_id, m.receiver
```

and result is: 
 [spec_id] => 5
            [height_id] => 3
            [size_id] => 2
            [qty] => 6
            [arrival_qty] => 4 (instead of 2 as in table)
            [movement_qty] => 2
            [warehouse_id] => 1
Why does it double qty? Where is mistake?

Comment: Can you show us your sample data by using http://sqlfiddle.com? This way we can fix and test the query directly

Comment: hm. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74c78/2 . I tried and SQLfiddle return right result. How it can be?

Comment: i will load full tables to sqlfiddle to analyze

Comment: I suggest you remove the GROUP BY and the aggregates, and run the query, and inspect the results. (Add the PK columns from each table to see what's really going on.) I suspect your tables have more row in them, more than shown in the question. Usually this kind of "doubling" of results is due to a partial cross join, one row in a table matching two rows in another table. The GROUP BY operation is collapsing the rows, and adding the `qty` from each row. With only one row in each table, I don't see that this result is possible.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bnn1m6

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bnn1vh

Comment: at second table 2 rows

Comment: so just remove GROUP?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79f1ec/1 i add second row to table and now it is with double

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're adding the `arrival_qty` twice somewhere in this code.:

```
SELECT ad.spec_id, ad.height_id, ad.size_id, (SUM(ad.qty)+SUM(md.qty)) as qty, SUM(ad.qty) as arrival_qty, SUM(md.qty) as movement_qty, a.warehouse_id FROM arrival_data ad
```

Or you might be passing in `arrival_qty` as 4.

It will be in our best wish for you to give us the full script of code to determine where the error is.

Comment: it doubles rows because movement_data has 2 rows with spec_id 5. How to change query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ad.spec_id, ad.height_id, ad.size_id, (SUM(ad.qty)+b.move_qty) as qty, SUM(ad.qty) as arrival_qty, b.move_qty as movement_qty, a.warehouse_id FROM arrival_data ad
LEFT JOIN arrivals a 
    ON ad.arrival_id = a.arrival_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(m.qty) as move_qty, m.size_id, m.height_id, m.spec_id, mb.receiver FROM movement_data m, movements mb WHERE mb.movement_id = m.movement_id GROUP BY m.size_id, m.height_id, m.spec_id, mb.receiver) b
    ON ad.size_id= b.size_id 
        AND ad.height_id = b.height_id 
        AND ad.spec_id = b.spec_id
        AND b.receiver = a.warehouse_id             

GROUP BY ad.spec_id, ad.size_id, ad.height_id, b.receiver
```

tried this one and at sql fiddle it works but at my sql it does not show movement qty